# RecyclerView keeps scrolling up whenever new item is added. How to fix this?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

So, I have a recyclerview that displays a list that is fetched from my Firebase database. But, each time a new item is added, the recyclerview scrolls upwards for no apparent reason. How do I fix this? I have gone through all the solutions on stackoverflow and tried to implement them but in vain.

I have disabled the animation and this still persists.

My code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_artcall_feed);
        setupBottomNavigationView();

        Artcall_feed_list = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.artcall_feed);

        mFeedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Artcall_Feed").child("general");
        mtoolbar = findViewById(R.id.genpage_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mtoolbar);


        Artcall_feed_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        Artcall_feed_list.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0);

        //Artcall_feed_list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = Artcall_feed_list.getItemAnimator();

        if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
            ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
        }

    }

 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser == null) {
        sendtoStart();
    }
    else {

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Feed_list, FundedArtcalls> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Feed_list, FundedArtcalls>(
                Feed_list.class,
                R.layout.single_artcall_feed_layout,
                ArtcallFeedActivity.FundedArtcalls.class,
                mFeedRef

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final FundedArtcalls viewHolder, final Feed_list model, final int position) {

                final String feed_item_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                viewHolder.setArtist_name(model.getArtist_name());
                viewHolder.setPerf_location(model.getPerf_location());
                new_percent = model.getPercent_funded();
                viewHolder.setPercent_funded(new_percent, old_percent);
                viewHolder.setCurrent_like_count(model.getCurrent_like_count());
                viewHolder.setTarget_like_count(model.getTarget_like_count());
                viewHolder.setLikeStatus(feed_item_id);
                viewHolder.setImage_url(model.getImage_url());                      

              }

        };

        Artcall_feed_list.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = Artcall_feed_list.getItemAnimator();

        if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
            ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: But isn't that the equivalent of disabling animation. Can you give me the correct solution then?

Comment: Where is the new item gets added?.

Comment: I'm using FirebaseUI. It's a library that takes care of all the item-adding and deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line "Artcall_feed_list.getItemAnimator (). SetChangeDuration (0);"

Comment: Haved you tried this library ?
https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators